# SharePoint Look and feel or navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, json-formatting

We are on SharePoint Online and I am wondering if there is a way to achieve our page like this site https://fmx.cpa.texas.gov/fmx/travel/textravel/meallodg/index.php with the left navigation and contents on the right side or body.

Any idea?

I found this https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/view-samples/content-navigator/README.md but it's not as same.

I am working on Communication Site.

Comment: What is the issue with the view formatting link you found? Is it not working for you or is it not what you expected? Also, do you want to achieve this using OOTB functionalities only or you are ready to use SPFx web parts as well (coding experience required)?

Comment: TY. I was wondering if someone already have SPFx ready and if I could borrow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looking for ready made SharePoint framework (SPFx web part) solutions, check below SPFx web part samples developed by community members and made available to everyone on open source GitHub repository:

1. [Page Navigator](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-page-navigator)
2. [Page Sections Navigation](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-page-sections-navigation)

You can take the code from this GitHub repository and enhance those web parts as per your requirements to suit to your requirements.